# Creating Dependent Dropdown list

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a 3 layered drop down list menu for my automotive company, I need each drop down menu to be dependent on the previous selected option.

For example: 
**CAR MAKE:** BMW
**BODY STYLE:** 3 Series
**ENGINE:** S52 3.2L I6

I don't even know what to search for, or how to implement it(Javascript, PHP, JSON, Ajax etc), can someone point me in the right direction on which would be the easiest way to go about building such a drop down menu? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this, you might want to use a library like [knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com/), which allows for separation between code and markup, thus making life much easier. Here is a knockout example implementation of what you are looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/pCc9w/4/

Html:

```
<select data-bind="options:data, optionsText:'name', value:selectedLevel1"></select>

    <!--ko with: selectedLevel1 -->
        <select data-bind="options:subitems, optionsText:'name', value:$root.selectedLevel2"></select>
<!--/ko-->



    <!--ko with: selectedLevel2 -->
<select data-bind="options:subitems, optionsText:'name', value:$root.selectedLevel3"></select>
    <!--/ko-->
```

Javascript:

```
var data = [
    {
        name:"level1",
        subitems:[
            {
                name:"level1.1",
                subitems:[
                    { name:"level1.1.1" },
                    { name:"level1.1.2" },
                    { name:"level1.1.3" }
                ]
            },
            {
                name:"level1.2",
                subitems:[
                    { name:"level1.2.1" },
                    { name:"level1.2.2" },
                    { name:"level1.2.3" }
                ]
            }]
    },
    {
        name:"level2",
        subitems:[
            {
                name:"level2.1",
                subitems:[
                    { name:"level2.1.1" },
                    { name:"level2.1.2" },
                    { name:"level2.1.3" }
                ]
            },
            {
                name:"level2.2",
                subitems:[
                    { name:"level2.2.1" },
                    { name:"level2.2.2" },
                    { name:"level2.2.3" }
                ]
            }]
    },    
]

    var dataViewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
    var mainViewModel = {
        data:dataViewModel,
        selectedLevel1:ko.observable(),
        selectedLevel2:ko.observable(),
        selectedLevel3:ko.observable()
    }



    ko.applyBindings(mainViewModel);
```

Keep in mind that this only solves the client-side part of the problem. On the server side, you need some way to obtain the data array and send it to the client. Probably you should use an MVC framework. Some examples are ruby on rails, django, asp.net MVC. PHP has lots of MVC frameworks too.

Comment: Thank you pax!
What if I the end result after the 3rd dropdown list was the same everytime? What I still need to use an MVC Framework for that?

Comment: @user2684799 No problem, glad to be of assistance. Remember to accept/upvote the answer if it was useful. I suggested using a server side MVC framework for building the data array, and for handling the response from the client. If you can do it with raw PHP, that's fine too. However, if you feel that the project might grow large at some point, use a framework from the start, it will make your life much easier later.

Comment: Hey thanks. Have you heard of Yii Framework? Looks like something I'd be able to master

Comment: @user2684799 Well, I have no experience with PHP, you should ask someone who is more experienced what framework is easier to learn.

Comment: I was hoping I could find a way to message you, but I couldn't. 

Would you accept $30 to help me set this up? I can give you access to my server etc.

Comment: @user2684799 Sorry man, I'm very busy for the next couple of weeks. You should try something like https://www.odesk.com/